# Euclid's Extended Algorithm Proof Clarification.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

I'm posititve a proof of validity has been exposed before. However, I came accross a proof by induction that I quite don't understand; namely, the inductive hyposthesis isn't quite clear to me. I understant up to $d=d_{k}$; it's the second part after this that I don't understand. I present the proof and hope someone'll be able to point out the base step, the inductive hypothesis, and the conclusion.

As an aside, please let me know of any keying mistakes I might've made with the subscripts.

Thanks in advance.

---

> Let $d_{\ -2}$ and $d_{\ -1}$ be positive integers. The ordinary division algorithm for $$\frac{d_{\ -2}}{d_{\ -1}}$$ gives a quotient $a_{0}$ and a remainder $d_{0}$ such that $$d_{\ -2}=a_{0}d_{\ -1}+d_{0}, \ \ \ \ \ 0\le d_{0}\lt d_{\ -1}.$$ If $d_{0}$ is $0$ we stop; otherwise the division algorighm for $$\frac{d_{\ -1}}{d_{0}}$$ gives a quotient $a_{1}$ and a remainder $d_{1}$ such that $$d_{\ -1}=a_{1}d_{0}+d_{1}, \ \ \ \ \ 0\le d_{1}\lt d_{0}.$$ If $d_{1}\not= 0,$ we continue onward getting, successively, \begin{align}d_{0} & =a_{2}d_{1}+d_{2}, \ \ \ \ \ 0\le d_{2}\lt d_{1},\\ d_{1} & =a_{3}d_{2}+d_{3}, \ \ \ \ \ 0\le d_{3}\lt d_{2},\\ \vdots\\ d_{k-2} & =a_{k}d_{k-1}+d_{k}, \ \ 0\le d_{k}\lt d_{k-1},\end{align} where it is assumed that $d_{j}\not=0$ if $j\lt k.$ Since $$d_{\ -1}\gt d_{0}\gt d_{1}\gt d_{2}\gt d_{3}\gt \dots d_{k-1}\gt d_{k}\ge 0,$$ it is clear that, sooner or later some $d_{j}$ will equal zero and, in fact, since each $d_{j}$ is at least one smaller than the $d_{j}$ before it we will come to a $d_{j}=0$ with $j\lt d_{\ -1}.$ If $d_{k+1}=0$ then $$d_{k-1}=a_{k-1}d_{k}.$$
>   Thus,  we may put these equations together as \begin{align}(1)\ d_{\ -2} & =a_{0}d_{\ -1}+d_{0}, \ \ \ \ \ 0\le d_{0}\lt d_{\ -1},\\ d_{\ -1} & =a_{1}d_{0}+d_{1}, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0\le d_{1}\lt d_{0},\\ \vdots\\ d_{k-2} & =a_{k}d_{k-1}+d_{k}, \ \ 0\le d_{k}\lt d_{k-1},\\ d_{k-1} & =a_{k+1}d_{k}.\end{align}

---

> **Theorem.** If $d_{-2}$ and $d_{-1}$ are positive integers and $d_{k}$ is found from the process of equations (1), then $$gcd(d_{\ -2},d_{\ -1})=d_{k}.$$
>   Further, we may find integers $r$ and $s$ in a systematic way from equations (1) such that $$rd_{\ -2}+sd_{\ -1}=d_{k}.$$

---

> *Proof.*$\ $$\ $Let $d=(d_{\ -2},d_{\ -1}).$ When we put (1) in the form \begin{align} d_{0} & =d_{\ -2}-a_{0} d_{\ -1},\\ d_{1} & =d_{\ -1}-a_{1} d_{0},\\ d_{2} & =d_{0}-a_{2} d_{1}, \\ \vdots \\d_{k} & =d_{k-2}-a_{k} d_{k-1},  \end{align}
>   we see that $d|d_{0}$, and then $d|d_{1},d|d_{2},\dots,d|d_{k}$. Therefore, 
>   $$(2)\ d \le  d_{k}.$$ On the other hand, by starting at the last of equations (1) and working up we see that in succession, $$d_{k}|d_{k-1},d_{k}|d_{k-2},\dots,d_{k}|d_{2},d_{k}|d_{1},d_{k}|d_{0},d_{k}|d_{\ -1},d_{k}|d_{\  -2}.$$ Thus $d_{k}$ is a common divisor of $d_{\ -1}$ and $d_{\ -2}$ and, therefore ,by the definition of the greatest common divisor, $$d_{k}\le d .$$ This, combined with equation (2), says that $$d_{k}=d,$$ as desired.
>
> ---
>
> It is most convenient to give an inductive proof of the last part of the theorem. The main idea is that if we can express $d_{J-2}$ and $d_{J-1}$  as combinations of $d_{\ -2}$ and $d_{\ -1}$, then we may use the equation $$d_{j}=d_{J-2}-a_{j}d_{J-1}$$
>   to express $d_{j}$ as a combination of $d_{\ -2}$ and $d_{\ -1}$ also. The actual induction is somewhat awkward since $d_{j-2}$ and $d_{j-1}$ are involved in getting the result for $d_{j}$. We may put things in the usual form for induction by complicating our induction hypothesis. Let $S_{n}$ be the statement: There are integers $r_{n-2},\ s_{n-2},\ r_{n-1},$ and $s_{n-1}$ such that $$d_{n-2}=r_{n-2}d_{\ -2}+s_{n-2}d_{\ -1},$$ $$d_{n-1}=r_{n-1}d_{\ -2}+s_{n-1}d_{\ -1}.$$ Our goal is to prove $S_{k+1}$ is true since the second part of $S_{k+1}$ says that there are integers $r_{k}$ and $s_{k}$ such that $$d_{k}=r_{k}d_{\ -2}+s_{k}d_{\ -1}.$$ First, we note that $$d_{\ -2}=1\cdot d_{\ -2}+0\cdot d_{\ -1},$$ $$d_{\ -1}=0\cdot d_{\ -2}+1\cdot d_{\ -1},$$ and thus $S_{0}$ is true. We now prove that if $0\le n \le k$ and $S_{n}$ is true, then $S_{n+1}$ is true. Suppose that $S_{n}$ is true so that there are integers $r_{n-2},\ s_{n-2},\ r_{n-1},$ and $s_{n-1}$ such that \begin{align}(3)\ d_{n-2} & =r_{n-2}d_{\ -2}+s_{n-2}d_{\ -1},\\ d_{n-1} & =r_{n-1}d_{\ -2}+s_{n-1}d_{\ -1}.\end{align} We see from (1) that $$d_{n}=d_{n-2}-a_{n}d_{n-1},$$ and if we substitute (3) into this we get \begin{align} d_{n} & =(r_{n-2}d_{\ -2}+s_{n-2}d_{\ -1})-a_{n}(r_{n-1}d_{\ -2}+s_{n-1}d_{\ -1}),\\ & =(r_{n-2}+a_{n}r_{n-1})d_{\ -2}+(s_{n-2}+a_{n}s_{n-1})d_{\ -1}\\ & =r_{n}d_{\ -2}+s_{n}d_{\ -1}, \end{align} where we have put $$r_{n}=r_{n-2}-a_{n}r_{n-1},$$ $$s_{n}=s_{n-2}-a_{n}s_{n-1}.$$ Thus we have integers $r_{n-1}$, $s_{n-1}$, $r_{n}$, and $s_{n}$ such that \begin{align} d_{n-1} & =r_{n-1}d_{\ -2}+s_{n-1}d_{\ -1},\\ d_{n} & =r_{n}d_{\ -2}+s_{n}d_{\ -1},\end{align} which is the statement $S_{n+1}$. Thus $S_{n+1}$ follows from $S_{n}$. Since $S_{0}$ is true $S_{1}$ follows from $S_{0}$, and then $S_{2}$ follows from $S_{1}$, $S_{3}$ from $S_{2},\dots,$ until finally $S_{k+1}$ follows from $S_{k}$. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the continued fraction version easier to remember than the (equivalent) version we often see.

$$  \gcd( 2537, 2311 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 2537 }{ 2311 } = 1 +  \frac{ 226 }{ 2311 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 2311 }{ 226 } = 10 +  \frac{ 51 }{ 226 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 226 }{ 51 } = 4 +  \frac{ 22 }{ 51 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 51 }{ 22 } = 2 +  \frac{ 7 }{ 22 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 22 }{ 7 } = 3 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 7 }{ 1 } = 7 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$ 
 Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccc}
 & & 1 & & 10 & & 4 & & 2 & & 3 & & 7 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 1 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 11 }{ 10 }   & &   \frac{ 45 }{ 41 }   & &   \frac{ 101 }{ 92 }   & &   \frac{ 348 }{ 317 }   & &   \frac{ 2537 }{ 2311 }  
 \end{array}
 $$ 
 $$  $$ 
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{ccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 1 }{ 1 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  10  \\  
  \frac{ 11 }{ 10 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  4  \\  
  \frac{ 45 }{ 41 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 101 }{ 92 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  3  \\  
  \frac{ 348 }{ 317 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  7  \\  
  \frac{ 2537 }{ 2311 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  0  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 2537 \cdot 317 - 2311 \cdot 348 = 1 $$